# Using a object node as a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, jquery-validate

How can I use a object node as a variable like in `newEndEventDate` below?

```
var val = $("form").validate({
    rules: {
        newEventDate: { required: true, regex: /^(19|20)\d\d-?(0[1-9]|1[012])-?(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$/ },
        newEndEventDate: { required: true, regex: /^(19|20)\d\d-?(0[1-9]|1[012])-?(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$/, greaterThan: newEventDate },                       
        newEventText: { required: true, maxlength: 200 },
    },
    messages: {
        ...
    }
}).form();
```

Using `newEventDate` inside `newEndEventDate` gives the error `'newEventDate' is undefined`. But if I comment out the `newEndEventDate:` line then the script works fine. This only occurs in IE10 and probably all other versions of IE. Works fine in Chrome and Firefox

Comment: Show us enough relevant HTML so that we can reproduce the error.  Also show where your `greaterThan` and `regex` methods are coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var rules = {
        newEventDate: { required: true, regex: /^(19|20)\d\d-?(0[1-9]|1[012])-?(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$/ },
        newEndEventDate: { required: true, regex: /^(19|20)\d\d-?(0[1-9]|1[012])-?(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$/ },                       
        newEventText: { required: true, maxlength: 200 },
    };
rules.newEndEventDate.greaterThan = rules.newEventDate;
var val = $("form").validate({
    rules: rules,
    messages: {
        ...
    }
}).form();
```